# Typing effect on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I searched for answers but nothing really works for me, so I will post my question here (sry for newbie mistakes).

I need a typing effect triggered on scrolling down, which runs backwards on scrolling up.

```js
// typing text
var _CONTENT = ["Test...test....test....test....test.....test"];

// Current sentence being processed
var _PART = 0;

// Character number of the current sentence being processed 
var _PART_INDEX = 0;

// Holds the handle returned from setInterval
var _INTERVAL_VAL;

// Element that holds the text
var _ELEMENT = document.querySelector("#text");

// Cursor element 
var _CURSOR = document.querySelector("#cursor");

// Implements typing effect
function Type() {
  // Get substring with 1 characater added
  var text = _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX + 1);
  _ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
  _PART_INDEX++;
}

// Implements deleting effect
function Delete() {
  // Get substring with 1 characater deleted
  var text = _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX - 1);
  _ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
  _PART_INDEX--;
}

// Start the typing effect on load
_INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Type, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="text"></div>
  <div id="cursor"></div>
</div>
```

Above I found an example of a typing effect, which I adapted to my needs and it works. 
Then I tried to surround a scroll-function (I left the other code as above) and there is no result.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
      function Type() {
        // Get substring with 1 characater added
        var text = _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX + 1);
        _ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
        _PART_INDEX++;
      }
    } else {
      function Delete() {
        // Get substring with 1 characater deleted
        var text = _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX - 1);
        _ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
        _PART_INDEX--;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="text"></div>
  <div id="cursor"></div>
</div>
```

Could anyone tell me where my mistake is? Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scroll up/down detection might not be working correctly.  Doing it like this should let you accurately detect direction:

```
var _top = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var _cur_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(_top < _cur_top)
    {
        Type();
    }
    else
    {
        Delete();
    }
    _top = _cur_top;    
});
```

You can put this in the same script block as your other code and just call Type() or Delete() instead of redefining those methods inside the scroll function.